# CoreML Multiple Input/Multiple Classifier output

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

After searching questions on SO and reddit, I can't figure out how to train a multiple input, multiple output classifier on a ML Text Classifier. I can train a single input, single output text classifier but that doesnt fit my use case.

Any help would be appreciated. I understand that there's no code to post, and that this is sort of a "show me how" question, but this information seems not readily available via searching and elsewhere, and would be beneficial to the community.

Answer (score 1):

The classifier objects provided by Core ML (and Create ML) are for very specific use cases. If you try to do anything more advanced than that, you'll have to create a custom model, such as your own neural network.